# Visual Studio 2010 Deployment Project supported by MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, msbuild, project

Do you know if there is anyway to deploy a VS2010 Deployment Project using msbuild? Is is supported? I know it was not for a long while but I couldn't find is something change.

If not, is WIX the only approach?

Comment: What artifacts are being deployed? In other words, do you really need a deployment project?

Comment: Deploy a deployment project?  What will you use to deploy the deployment of the deployment project?  Copy the setup.exe file.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a deploy project - i assume you mean a vdproj? But not directly with msbuild. You have to wrap an exec target around devenv.exe. So you'd have to have visual studio on your build machine.

Comment: Thanks! I finally decided to use WIX... It makes my deployment more independent...

Comment: Wix is a great solution. Good luck.